# Como enviar para o Controller inputs com "name" dinamicos? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo um quiz game, onde o usuário tem vários input's para preencher.

Só que não estou conseguindo desenvolver a lógica para realizar a comparação dos dados inseridos com os dados do banco.

**Segue a view:**

```
   <div class="container text-center">
    <?php
        echo form_open_multipart('questionario/gabarito');
    ?>
    <?php foreach($imagens as $key=> $imagem):?>
    <div class="area-imagem position-relative">

        <div class="mb-3">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/upload/'.$imagem['caminhoImagem']) ?>" width="720" height="auto" style="border: 1px solid rgb(185, 182, 182, 185);"> 
        </div>
        <?php foreach($imagem['marcacoes'] as $key=> $marcacao):?>
            <div class="ponto" id="<?=$marcacao['idMarcacao']?>" style="top:<?=$marcacao['coordY']?>px; left:<?=$marcacao['coordX']?>px"><b></b></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="<?=$marcacao['idMarcacao']?>"><b> - </b></label>
                <input name="<?=$marcacao['idMarcacao']?>" type="text">
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3" value="Finalizar">
    <?php 
        echo form_close(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor seu problema? Algum erro? Entrada e saída esperada...

Comment: Os inputs do formulário recebem como name o ID da linha da tabela onde encontra-se a resposta correta. Eu precisaria recuperar através do Controller cada um desses 'name', mas como são dinâmicos eu não estou conseguindo. Eu gostaria de saber como passo para o Controller esses "names".

Comment: Se você acessar `$this->input->post/get(null)` deve obter a lista com todos valores passados, dependendo do método definido no formulário, deve usar o `get` ou `post`